# Spring Boot Basic Authentication is ignoring Authorization Header when I send JSESSIONID?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, http-authentication

I'm doing a Basic Authentication using Spring Security. My Security Adapter looks like this:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("pass")).authorities("ROLE_USER");
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/securityNone").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().and().cors().and().csrf().disable();
        }
    }
```

When I use the browser or a REST client to make the request I set the `Authorization` header with the user and password encoded in Base64. And it works fine, the server returns a `JSESSIONID` and it is stored in a Cookie.

My confusion comes after the first authentication. When I try to make subsequent requests but change the `Authorization` header **it still works** giving me status `200 OK`. I have noticed that it also sends the `JSESSIONID`.

So my question is: Does the Basic Security validates the `Authorization` header only once?

Also: When I change the `JSESSIONID` cookie on the browser the request also still works.

Can someone shed a light on how this process works?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If there is already a valid `Authentication` in the session the header will be ignored. If you change the session id (or remove the cookie) but leave the authentication header you will just re-authenticate.

Comment: So spring security will ignore the Authorization header if I have a valid JSESSIONID?

Comment: Yes, unless you use Spring Security in a stateless fashion, then it will never store information in the session.